# Style PHP mail form into table

Tags: php, email, radio-button, html-email

I have a simple php mail form whcih sends an email to the admin but at the moment it is just coming through as a standard looking text.

I need it so it comes through in a table with each section from the form on a new row in the table.

Also it is using some radio buttons for some options on the form. Is it possible for the radio button sections to come through as the example below.

Renewed Framework Assessments    |  "Radio button selected"

Renewed Framework Assessments 2  |  "Radio button selected"

Renewed Framework Assessments 3  |  "None"

And if so if an option for the radio button was selected it would be "GREEN" if nothing was selected it says "NONE" and is in red.

This is the code I am using at the moment:

```
<?php

  $email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
  $name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
  $radio1 = $_REQUEST['radio1'] ;
  $radio2 = $_REQUEST['radio2'] ;
  $radio3 = $_REQUEST['radio3'] ;
  $radio4 = $_REQUEST['radio4'] ;
  $address = $_REQUEST['address'] ;
  $postcode = $_REQUEST['postcode'] ;
  $tel = $_REQUEST['tel'] ;


  mail( "email@domain.com", "APPROVAL REQUEST FORM",  "Renewed Framework Assessments: $radio1\nSP Assessment Analysis Program (Demo Version): $radio2\nRenewed Framework Mental Maths Assessments: $radio3\nRenewed Framework Word Problem Books: $radio4\nFrom: $name\nEmail: $email\nAddress: $address\nPostcode: $postcode\nTelephone Number: $tel\n",'From: order@mathsbooksforchildren.co.uk');

  header( "Location: http://domain.com/approval-request-form/" );

?>
```

Comment: chk this link http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: No attempt to answer the question yourself, mail injection vulnerabilities and using `$_REQUEST`. Seems like what you actually need to do is hire some one to do this. SO is for specific problems, not doing work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format your message in this way....

```
     $headers  = "From: order@mathsbooksforchildren.co.uk\r\n"; 
     $headers .= "Content-type: text/html charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n"; 
     $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Some title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
     <tr><td>Email</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Email</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Nema</td><td>'.$name.'</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Radio1</td><td>'.$radio1.'</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Radio1</td><td>'.$radio3.'</td></tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>'

    ';
```

Comment: I have tired this but the values are not coming through on the email it just shows $email, $radio1, $name etc.

Comment: Great that works fine, is it possible for any radio buttons that are selectd for the value to be green and if nothing selected it says None in red?

Comment: You can check the condition something like this..if($radio1 =='1'){ echo '<p style='color:green'>'.$radio1.'<p>'}else{'<p style='color:red'>'.$radio1.'<p>'}

Comment: you can accept the answer to make it available for all users..:)

Comment: With the new code in your comment im getting this error "unexpected T_IF" any thoughts?

Comment: This code is working fine ... if($redio1 =='1')
{
 echo '<p style="color:#00FF00">'.$redio1.'<p>';
}
else
{
 echo '<p style="color:#FF0000">'.$redio1.'<p>';
}

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11823/discussion-between-matt-and-pramod-kumar-sharma)

Answer (score 2):

In order to send an HTML email, you have to set the appropriate headers.

For instance :

```
    $headers  = "From: order@mathsbooksforchildren.co.uk\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n";
```

And then just write your html in a variable like this :

```
    $message = '
<html>
<head>
  <title>Some title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
';
```

With the table set as you wish, the same as you would set HTML in a page and just send it with th headers like this :

```
mail("email@domain.com", "APPROVAL REQUEST FORM", $message, $headers);
```

But in general i would recommend you use some class for your mailing, working with the default `mail` function can result in alot of troubles at some point.
Try [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) or [PHP Mailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Comment: Ok so I have it coming through as a table but I put in $radio1 in the table to get that value but it is just coming through as $radio1 and not the value which was selected.

Comment: Try breaking the string and concating the variable

Comment: Im not sure what you mean can you help me out a bit more?